# Prepared statement to update an attribute for a specific user - JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a user record in a database. What query should I use to update the `project_key` attribute of a specific user, I find by his `login` key. I tried to select the user and then use the `updateString` method of the result set. I also made the result set `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `CONCUR_UPDATABLE`, but that didn't do anything. So what should the query be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for SQL query? What is this string? Sorry for asking this, but I couldn't understand your question even after reading it 3 times

Comment: Yes the sql query. It's because the prepared statement is formed from a string. I'll edit the question.

Comment: For Sql query, you will have to give more info on tables involved and the column that you want to update

Comment: Can you post your code? What's the code you tried and what didn't work? Your question is too theory to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PreparedStatement's [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

```
String update = "UPDATE table SET project_key=? WHERE login=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.preparedStatement(update);
pstmt.setString(1, newKey);
pstmt.setString(2, userLogin);

int testForUpdate = pstmt.executeUpdate();

System.out.println(int>0?"Update was done":"No update occured");
```